# Where does it say that any part of hands is left dry during wudu invalidates it

Tags: wudu, reference-request

Is it in Quran or authentic hadith that during our ablution/wudu, if we leave any part (even a centimeter) of our hands dry, the wudu becomes invalid or less reward-worthy?

If so, please share the verse from Quran and/or authentic hadith reference.

I am confused about nailpaint matter. I want to prioritize and follow Allah InshaAllah but also want to look presentable and enjoy, as much as is permissible.

Answer (score 1):

According to below evidence water should touch the skin. This means that a person must remove everything covering the body parts he washes during ablution that would prevent water from reaching his skin. This applies to those who work with paint. If this substance sticks hard onto the body parts they wash during ablution to the point that water cannot reach the skin, one is obligated to take it off by using paint remover before performing ablution.

> Prophet (ﷺ)to Abu Dharr: “If you find water, then let it touch your
> skin, for that is good.” Narrated by Abu Dawood (332); classed as
> saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.

In another Hadith:

> Prophet (ﷺ) saw a person offering prayer, and on the back of his foot
> a small part equal to the space of a dirham remained unwashed; the
> water did not reach it. The Prophet (ﷺ) commanded him to repeat the
> ablution and prayer. Abu Dawood Book 1, Number 0175